# Spring boot + OAuth2 security & request filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have implemented Spring boot based REST API with OAuth2 for authentication. I had  to validate all request using `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` to check Authorization header token bearer & validate it. Also, before validating request using OAuth filter, i need to have custom filter for "ALL" request to check few mandatory request header param.

Internally if any exception occurs `/error` is redirected & this doesn't need to go through `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`, this request can be skipped.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/error").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
   // both configuration validates even "ERROR" request.
http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/error").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

```
// security config with filter 
    http.addFilterBefore(new APISignatureFilter(), OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.class).authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/error").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

I have implemented OncePerRequestFilter & it is not getting called for any request. This has to be called before OAuth filter.

```
@Component
public class APISignatureFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
 }
```

Let me know what is going wrong in this security config.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement AuthenticationEntryPoint interface from spring security

```
 @Component
 public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
 private static final Logger logger = 
 LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);
@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                     HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                     AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    logger.error("Responding with unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
    httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
            "Sorry, You're not authorized to access this resource.");
} 
}
```

and you need to define this entrypoint in your spring security configuration like

```
         http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(//bean of 
           JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)//
```

if any exception arises in your filter this will be invoked